# Android hide numbers like password

Tags: android, textview

I want to know how to hide some numbers in TextView and some are shown just like that
  **(****-****-1234)**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Method...

```
public static String StrRpl(String str) {

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < chars.length && j < 5; i++) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
            chars[i] = '*';
            j++;
        }
    }
    str = new String(chars);
    return str;
}
```

**Output :** *****234

pass a string to this method and it will return string with '*' character till first 5 characters (You can change your number of count.. current is 5)